# TypeError: Buffer.alloc is not a function

Tags: node.js

From node docs, I am trying some code from [`Buffer`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html) .

When I execute this statement

```
const buf = Buffer.from('hello world', 'ascii');
```

it throws an exception: `TypeError: Buffer.alloc is not a function`

My node version is v5.7.1.

I don't understand why?

Here is the error screen.

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The new `Buffer` API is only available in v5.10.0+, so you'll need to upgrade to use it.

If you want to view the docs for v5.7.1, you can go [here](https://nodejs.org/docs/v5.7.1/api/).

FWIW the new `Buffer` API is also now available in node v4.x as of v4.5.0.

Comment: So,my questions which version one should follow?

Comment: It depends on your node version. If you want to upgrade, then use the newer docs, otherwise you can use the link for the older docs. No matter what there are always versioned docs (even the latest version) so you can see what applies for a particular version of node.

Answer (score 4):

This error occurs due to missmatch node version so please node version on my machine like this:

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
```

Answer (score 1):

if you can do these commands,it should be work.

step 1:

first,  you can type this command `sudo npm cache clean -f`

step 2:
   Now,you can type this command
     `sudo npm install -g n`

step 3:

Now ,you should enter this command
   `sudo n 6.4.0`

step 4:

finally, you should enter this command for restart the your system or reboot

`shutdown -h now`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to restart you can just do this:

```
sudo apt install curl
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo bash -
sudo apt install nodejs
node -v
```

Instructions from here: https://websiteforstudents.com/install-the-latest-node-js-and-nmp-packages-on-ubuntu-16-04-18-04-lts/

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason my alloc function was a couple objects down.
Please verify your console.log(Buffer)

```
   let Buffer = require('buffer');
   console.log(Buffer)
   data = Buffer.Buffer.alloc(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced the same issue.
Just do `Buffer.Buffer.alloc()`, it works fine then :)

hope it helps