# TypeError: Buffer.alloc is not a function while accessing firebase tools

Tags: node.js, firebase, npm

I am trying to access firebase console from my terminal, but due to this error I am not able too

[image]

I checked this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36499840/3287355) too, but didn't quite understand as I haven't worked on node.js before

Thanks in advance

Comment: You're using an outdated version of Node.js. Which OS/distro are you using?

Comment: @robertklep, I am using Ubuntu 16.04. It worked fine few days ago. All of a sudden it started showing this error since morning

Comment: What does `node --version` return?

Comment: It returns v4.2.6

Comment: Well, that's too old. For Ubuntu, I would suggest using these instructions to install a more recent version of Node.js: https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions Perhaps you need to uninstall the currently installed version first.

Comment: It worked for me. You should post this as answer.

Answer (score 0):

`Buffer.alloc` was added in 5.10, as stated in the history detail, [here](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_alloc_size_fill_encoding), due to security issues with unfilled buffers. Hence implementors had to change that quickly, possibly breaking older Node clients. Also I'd suggest, when working with cloud functions, to match their Node version, which (at the time of writing) is Node 6.14.0.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it worked for me.  Lots of trial and error:

```
npm install buffer -g
```

tested instance with:

```
const <yourInstanveVar> = require('buffer').Buffer.allocUnsafe(<yourSize>) 

console.log(<yourInstanceVar>);
```

Returned (Node JS v8.12.0):

```
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PhpStorm 2017.1.1\bin\runnerw.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" F:\JSX\Development\Scratchpads\buffersFS.js
<Buffer 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00>

Process finished with exit code 0
```