# npm ERR! Buffer.alloc is not a function

Tags: node.js, npm, angular2-routing

I am new in Angular 2. I want to install npm in my windows system. but I got the error below:

```
npm ERR! Buffer.alloc is not a function

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\swayeole\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-09-07T10_04_
08_794Z-debug.log
```

- nmp version : 5.4.0
- node version : 4.4.7

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: Buffer.alloc is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36499840/typeerror-buffer-alloc-is-not-a-function)

Comment: @stdob--, what do you mean?

Comment: You need newest version of node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, install a LTS or LATEST version of node.js at http://nodejs.org

After install, NPM version could be a lower version, but it works well.

You can update to new version of NPM