# Push failed ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)

Tags: node.js, git, heroku, npm

I'm having issues deploying NodeJS app to Heroku. 
This is the error:

```
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote: 
remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
remote:        
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true
remote:        NODE_VERBOSE=false
remote:        NODE_ENV=production
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
remote: 
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  5.3.0
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
remote:        
remote:        Resolving node version 5.3.0...
remote:        Downloading and installing node 5.3.0...
remote:        Detected package-lock.json: defaulting npm to version 5.x.x
remote:        Bootstrapping npm 5.x.x (replacing 3.3.12)...
remote:        npm 5.5.1 installed
remote: 
remote: -----> Restoring cache
remote:        Skipping cache restore (not-found)
remote: 
remote: -----> Building dependencies
remote:        Installing node modules (package.json + package-lock)
remote:        npm ERR! Buffer.alloc is not a function
remote:        
remote:        npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote:        npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2017-10-21T22_24_56_159Z-debug.log
remote: 
remote: -----> Build failed
remote:        
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
remote:        
remote:        If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
remote:        https://help.heroku.com/
remote:        
remote:        Love,
remote:        Heroku
remote:        
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to young-ridge-96999.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/young-ridge-96999.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/young-ridge-96999.git
```

I have tried the suggestions on other Stack Overflow questions:
the `.gitignore` for the app has `node_modules/`

the package.json has

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
```

Ive tried making a new branch and pushing to Heroku with new branch

and

```
git add .
git commit -a -m'comment' 
git push
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: Buffer.alloc is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36499840/typeerror-buffer-alloc-is-not-a-function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's most likely due to you using an old version of Node. You can install the latest version with [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm#usage). Specifying exactly what version of npm you are using locally (`npm --version`), in package.json could also help, but I suggest upgrading to the latest version of Node.