# Postgresql does not work in node.js. "require('pg') " returns error

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, database, postgresql

Postgresql does not work in node.js. My node.js code is as below.

```
var  Client  = require('pg');
```

This code returns following error:

```
(My project directory)/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:316
var emptyBuffer = Buffer.alloc(0)
                         ^

TypeError: Buffer.alloc is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> ((My project directory) /node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:316:26)
    at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> ((My project directory)/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:20:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
```

What should I do for using 'pg' library?

I am beginner of javascript and node.js, so I may have made some basic mistakes. Anyone please help me.

I am using Linux(ubuntu 16.04).

I have installed postgresql which works through psql commands. 
I tried npm install pg --save and node_modules directory is successfully made.

npm version is 3.5.2.
postgresql version is 9.5.17

Comment: Seems you should upgrade node, pls check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36499840/typeerror-buffer-alloc-is-not-a-function)

Comment: Thank you for you advice. Yes, I found my node version was quite old. I installed node and npm through apt-get command, but I found I should have use n command instead. I write down what I did; apt-get install npm node -> npm install -g n -> n install lts -> sudo apt-get purge node npm -> log in and logout -> node --version //v10.15.3 -> Now the above code runs without error message.